# Trouble getting a YQL table working

Tags: yql

So I'm trying to set up a YQL table using the API at http://www.teamliquid.net/video/streams/?filter=live&xml=1 but having some issues.

Here's my table definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table xmlns="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/schema/table.xsd">
    <meta>
        <author>TL.net</author>
        <description>TL.net's streams</description>
        <documentationURL>none</documentationURL>
        <sampleQuery>select * from {table}</sampleQuery>
    </meta>
    <bindings>
        <select itemPath="streamlist" produces="XML">
            <urls>
                <url>http://www.teamliquid.net/video/streams/?xml=1</url>
            </urls>         
            <inputs>
                <key id="filter" type="xs:string" paramType="query" />
            </inputs>
        </select>
     </bindings>
</table>
```

Running `use "store://q5awkFLmEqteFVOTUJbQ6h" as tl; select * from tl where filter="live"` yields the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="0" yahoo:created="2012-02-13T22:14:48Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <diagnostics>
        <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
        <url execution-start-time="1" execution-stop-time="33"
            execution-time="32" proxy="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[store://q5awkFLmEqteFVOTUJbQ6h]]></url>
        <url execution-start-time="35" execution-stop-time="232"
            execution-time="197" http-status-code="406"
            http-status-message="Not Acceptable" proxy="DEFAULT"><![CDATA[http://www.teamliquid.net/video/streams/?xml=1&filter=live]]></url>
        <user-time>232</user-time>
        <service-time>258</service-time>
        <build-version>25247</build-version>
    </diagnostics> 
    <results/>
</query>
```

I really can't figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the debug statements, you can see that YQL is reading from your source URL: `http://www.teamliquid.net/video/streams/?xml=1&filter=live`, but is receiving back an HTTP 406 Not Acceptable error message.

HTTP 406 is meant to cover cases where the server cannot respond in any of the requested (Accept header) formats. I don't know how that applies in this case, but the teamliquid.net source mentions the following:

> gzip encoding is required, please also send a valid User-Agent with the name of your application / site and contact info. This page and the XML are updated every five minutes, please do not poll more frequently than every five minutes or you may risk being IP banned. If you have any questions, please PM R1CH.

I suspect it's one of two things:

1. The YQL servers are not requesting data in gzip or compressed format
2. The teamliquid.net servers are blocking YQL